# Removing duplicates in a text file before converting to a CSV

Tags: python, file, csv

I am looking to identify duplicates in a raw textfile I have, once a duplicate has been identified, I want to ignore it when creating a new CSV file.

```
raw_file_reader = csv.DictReader(open(raw_file), delimiter='|')
```

Keep in mine raw file is a simple .txt file

```
with open('file') as f:
  seen = set()
  for line in f:
      line_lower = line.lower()
      if line_lower in seen:
          print(line)
      else:
          seen.add(line_lower)
```

I can find the duplicates using sets

```
for row in raw_file_reader:
            if ('Symbol' in row):
                symbol = row['Symbol']
            elif ('SYMBOL' in row):
                symbol = row['SYMBOL']
            else:
                raise exception

            if symbol not in symbol_lookup:
                continue
```

I am just not sure how to actually ignore the duplicates before converting to the csv file.

Comment: It would help if you included a sample of your raw text file and also showed how you want the output to look.

Comment: @MartinEvans Added sample

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `csv` library to do this.  Additionally, there is a built in way to enumerate items.  So, let's use that.

```
import csv
with open("in.txt","r") as fi, open("out.csv","w") as fo:
    writer = csv.writer(fo, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(enumerate(set(fi.read().split("|"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove duplicates by storing all entries in a set as you go along as follows:

```
import csv

seen = set()
output = []

source_file = "file.csv"

with open(source_file, 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')

    for row in csv_input:
        if tuple(row) not in seen:
            output.append(row)
            seen.add(tuple(row))

with open(source_file, 'wb') as f_output:        
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows(output)
```

Giving you an output file:

```
20100830,TECD,1500,4300,N
20100830,TECH,100,100,N
20100830,TECUA,100,391,N
20100830,TEF,1300,1300,N
20100830,TEG,900,1900,N
```

This works by converting each whole row into a tuple which can then be stored as a set. This makes testing for duplicate lines straight forward.

Tested on Python 2.7.12

Comment: I've though of this, however I dont want to create a new csv file entirely, I just want dont want the duplicates to be transferred to the csv file.

Comment: For small files you can read it into memory and then overwrite the file. Or delete and rename once it has finished. I will update it to overwrite your input file.

Comment: I've also added how my current csv output looks after the .txt has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a custom iterator that will return the original file lines removing duplicates:

```
class Dedup:
    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.fd = fd       # store the original file object
        self.seen = set()  # initialize an empty set for lines
    def __next__(self):        # the iterator method
        while True:
            line = next(self.fd)
            if not line in self.seen:
                self.seen.add(line)
                return line
            # print("DUP>", line.strip(), "<") # uncomment for tests
    def __iter__(self):        # make the iterator compatible Python 2 and 3
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.__next__()
    def __enter__(self):       # make it a context manager supporting with
        return self
    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        self.fd.close()        # cleanup
```

You can then create your DictReader simply:

```
with Dedup(open(raw_file)) as fd:
   reader = csv.DictReader(fd, delimiter='|')
   for row in reader:
        # process each now unique row...
```

But beware! This will require that all lines are stored in the set, meaning that the original file must fit in memory.